# PGFPlots: How does one plot a wave packet?

Tags: pgfplots

Given the equation `2\cos(kx - wt)\cos(.5\Delta k(x - \frac{\Delta w}{\Delta k}t))`.  How can I plot this in `pgfplots`?

- `k` is the wave number
- `w` is the frequency
- `\Delta k` and `\Delta w` are both `\ll 1`
- We also have this relationship `w = -k^3`

If I plotted this in Python, I would define `t = linspace(-10, 10, 500000)` or whatever the range of `t` I need, but I don't know how to handle the parameter `t` in `pgfplots`.

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      x min = -10,
      x max = 10,
      y min = -2,
      y max = 2,
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle, 
      samples = 1000
      ]
     \addplot[red] {2 * cos(deg()) * cos(deg())};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It will look something like:

[image]

Comment: The second part of your question reads like an answer. What's the question?

Comment: @Jan the title says how can I plot a wave packet and then after the equation I ask how can I plot this (referring to the previous equation).  Then I give a basic layout of a MWE and an image of what a wave packet looks like.  So how can you not determine what the question is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need some kind of modulating function, e.g. an elementary Gauss curve like `exp(-0.25*x^2)`. Take look at this basic approach.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-5,
      xmax=5,
      ymin=-2,
      ymax=2,
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=middle, 
      samples = 1000
    ]
      \addplot[red] {2*exp(-0.25*x^2)*cos(deg(10*x))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

**Update**

A plot that looks more like in the presented picture could look like this. Note that is uses `sin(deg(0.5*x))^2` for the modulation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-10,
      xmax=10,
      ymin=-2,
      ymax=2,
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=middle,
      samples = 1000
    ]
%       \addplot[red] {2*exp(-0.25*x^2)*cos(deg(10*x))*cos(deg(x))};
       \addplot[blue,domain=-10:10] {2*sin(deg(0.5*x))^2*cos(deg(10*x))*cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: So I can't use two cosine functions to produce this?  I would like to be able to do this by not changing the function since this is a solution to the linear KdV equation.

Comment: Of course you can. Just replace my exemplary `cos(deg(10*x))` with your solving function. For more details it could help if you give the exact function with all the parameters. Note that you can only use one variable like `x` in such 2D plots.

Comment: But where and how do you come up with the exponential piece?  Is it related or just made up?  The exact function is the linear PDE `u_t + u_{xxx} = 0` where we are only looking at the solution that is given in the post.

Comment: As I already said, the exponential function is only an example for the modulation that you need to create the wave packet. You could replace it by e.g. `sin(deg(x))^2` to get a plot that looks more like the one in the picture you presented in your question.

Comment: Then what I don't understand is if I plot this in Python, I don't need this extra function to produce the desired results.  When we are adding this modulation function, is it changing the actually solution plot?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Python. The modulation only creates the wave packet. And a Gauss function creates a Gaussian wave packet.

Comment: If its based entirely on cosine, it should repeat like the image I included in the post.

Comment: @dustin: No. The modulation is the crucial part. See the example in my update.